# NSManagedObject with reactive objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, reactive

Consider this JSON

```
“data” : [  {
         - -  - - -  some user data   - - - - - 
        “A” : [ {
         - - - -  A’s data - - — - - - -  — - -    
              “a” : [ {
         - - - - -    a’s data - - - - - - - - - -

   “ a1” : [ {
         - - — - -   b’s data — — — }] } } } ] ] ]
```

Based on this I need to check inside a object `a1` is there or not. If `a1` is there, means listener will update by using Reactive objective-C. Can anyone please help me on this ?

Answer (score 3):

use below code. Hope this helps

```
/*
  convert JSON to NSDictionary
*/
NSDictionary *bodyDict = [utility convertStringToDictionary:jsonString];

if([bodyDict objectForKey:@“a1”])
{
   //Post your listener notification
}
```

Code to Convert string to NSDictionary

```
-(NSDictionary *)convertStringToDictionary:(NSString *)jsonString{

    NSError * err;
    NSData *data =[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary * response = nil;

    if(data!=nil){
        response = (NSDictionary *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
    }

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the only `a1` values in Json data.
Using the the following line to get `a1` values are available in Json or not,

```
NSMutableArray *Arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
Arr = [JsonData valueForKeyPath:@"data.A.a.a1"];

if(Arr.count == 0)   NSLog(@"Update : YES");
else   NSLog(@"Update : NO");
```